# Implicit casting - which cast is used

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a base and child class and a bit of multiple inheritance:

```
class Child : public Base, public AnotherBase
{
};
```

and a function `foo(Base* b)`. I've also instantiated a `Child* c`. I then call `foo(c)`.

The compiler makes an implicit cast here. But does it take a C-style cast, a `static_cast<Base*>` or something else?

Comment: The C++ compiler does an [*implicit conversion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast), and that link should tell you all you need to know (although it is hard to read and understand at a quick glance).

Comment: So if my boss has written `foo(static_cast<Base*>(c))` can I safely remove the `static_cast`?

Comment: Yes, a pointer to a child class is always implicitly convertible to a pointer to a base class.

Comment: @HompMomper maybe you have another overload taking `AnotherBase*` and that's why it was made explicit ?

Comment: No we don't have another overload. Perhaps we did once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static_cast` and C-style casts are ways of the programmer explicitly asking for a type conversion. Your example is a standard implicit conversion which is described separately rather than in terms of explicit conversions.

Your example is known as a *derived-to-base conversion* and is defined in `[conv.ptr]/2` in the standard:

> `N3337:` **A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `D`”, where `D` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `B`”, where `B` is a base class of `D`.** If `B` is an inaccessible or ambiguous base class of `D`, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. The result of the conversion is a pointer to the base class subobject of the derived class object. The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type.

In other words, a `D*` is always implicitly convertible to a `B*` with the same `const` and `volitile` qualifications.